# php str_ireplace without losing case

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

is it possible to run str_ireplace without it destroying the original casing?

For instance:

```
$txt = "Hello How Are You";
$a = "are";
$h = "hello";
$txt = str_ireplace($a, "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>".$a."</span>", $txt);
$txt = str_ireplace($h, "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>".$h."</span>", $txt);
```

this all works fine, but the result outputs:

```
[hello] How [are] You
```

instead of:

```
[Hello] How [Are] You
```

(square brackets being the color background)

Thanks.

Comment: Also i'd like to add, the reason i use ireplace is that i want it to change even in lowercase, but if uppercase i want it to keep its capital.

Comment: internally `str_ireplace` converts `$search` and `$replace` to lowercase to find matches - it's not an answer, but explains why you're having the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```
$txt = preg_replace("#\\b($a|$h)\\b#i", 
  "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>$1</span>", $txt);
```

... or, if you want to highlight the whole array of words (being able to use metacharacters as well):

```
$txt = 'Hi! How are you doing? Have some stars: * * *!';
$array_of_words = array('Hi!', 'stars', '*');

$pattern = '#(?<=^|\W)(' 
       . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array_of_words))
       . ')(?=$|\W)#i';

echo preg_replace($pattern, 
      "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>$1</span>", $txt);
```

Comment: @user1483508 Note that your original code from the question works as well. And that's why you should **not** use `preg_replace()` as it is slower. Don't understand what's the problem actually

Comment: @hek2mgl: It's because i needed it to work for uppercase, lowercase and mixed without it changing it to lowercase in the output.

Comment: The code you've posted will output the expected results. Please show exactly what is your current output and what is the expected output

Comment: Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: You're not missing anything, problem was solved with the first post.
I think i just worded my initial post wrong for some people.

Comment: @hek2mgl I can, probably. ) The point of OP is being able to wrap both 'hello' and 'HELLO' in "Hello, this is some example of HELLO hello" string. `str_ireplace` will replace both of them with _one_ variant of 'hello' string - either uppercase of lowercase.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Currently I still don't get it. Will read all again later, sometimes this helps ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Check this [demo](http://codepad.org/HGNgODWR), perhaps it'll help too. )

Comment: Got it! :) thanks!  +1 (already up-voted your post, can't do twice ;)

Comment: You could just do what you're doing and then `ucwords($result)` the output

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd want something along these lines:  Find the word as it is displayed, then use that to do the replace.

```
function highlight($word, $text) {
    $word_to_highlight = substr($text, stripos($text, $word), strlen($word));
    $text = str_ireplace($word, "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>".$word_to_highlight."</span>", $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for too

Comment: Actually this one seems to have an issue with multiple occurances of the search string, first one is fine (kept in original format) but subsequent ones get converted

Answer (score 1):

Not beautiful, but should work.

```
function str_replace_alt($search,$replace,$string)
{
    $uppercase_search = strtoupper($search);
    $titleCase_search = ucwords($search);
    $lowercase_replace = strtolower($replace);
    $uppercase_replace = strtoupper($replace);
    $titleCase_replace = ucwords($replace);

    $string = str_replace($uppercase_search,$uppercase_replace,$string);
    $string = str_replace($titleCase_search,$titleCase_replace,$string);
    $string = str_ireplace($search,$lowercase_replace,$string);

    return $string;
}
```