# Replace several words in string using associative array keeping original case intact

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I want to match an array against a text string where words matching with the array keys will be replaced by a span tag with a title with the matching array value.

I can do that with str_ireplace but then the matched words lose their case:

```
$glossary = array(
    'word1' => '<span title="Explanation for Word 1">word1</span>',
    'word2' => '<span title="Explanation for Word 2">word2</span>',
    'word3' => '<span title="Explanation for Word 3">word3</span>'
);

$text = "This is a text about Word1. We also talk about word2 and WORD3. Also woRd3, word2 and WORD1";

list($keys, $values) = array_divide($glossary);

$result = str_ireplace($keys, $values, $text);
```

As said, this works but in this solution all matching words will be in lowercase.

**What I want to achieve is this:**

```
'This is a text about <span title="Explanation for Word 1">Word1</span>. 
We also talk about <span title="Explanation for Word 2">word2</span> and
<span title="Explanation for Word 3">WORD3</span>.
Also <span title="Explanation for Word 3">woRd3</span>, 
<span title="Explanation for Word 2">word2</span>
and <span title="Explanation for Word 1">WORD1</span>'
```

Do the replacements and **keep the case intact**.

I found a great reply that came close but it only works with the addition of the span tag around the matched words, it does not add a second variable for the title ([php str_ireplace without losing case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740116/php-str-ireplace-without-losing-case)).

I don't know enough regex (It dazzles me) to change it by adding a second variable for the span titles:

```
$txt = 'Hi! How are you doing? Have some stars: * * *!';
$array_of_words = array('Hi!', 'stars', '*');

$pattern = '#(?<=^|\W)(' 
       . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array_of_words))
       . ')(?=$|\W)#i';

echo preg_replace($pattern, 
      "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>$1</span>", $txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this replace in loop:

```
$txt = 'Hi! How are you doing? Have some stars: * * *!';
$glossary = array(
    'Hi!'   => 'title 1',
    'stars' => 'title 2',
    '*'     => 'title 3'
);
$result = $txt;
foreach ($glossary as $keyword => $title) {
    $pattern = '#(?<=^|\W)('.preg_quote($keyword).')(?=$|\W)#i';
    $result  = preg_replace($pattern, "<span title='{$title}'>$1</span>", $result);
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with some common PHP functions.

1. Create an array of patterns from your `keys` to search in a case-insensitive manner with `preg_replace_callback`.
2. Pass the `$glossary` to the anonymous function in `preg_replace_callback` and get the value (the `<span>` title) by the lowercased current match value, and once found, replace the lowercase `wordX` with the match.

This is [PHP code](http://ideone.com/t3Dz87):

```
$pttrns = array_map(function ($val) {return "/" . preg_quote($val) . "/i"; },
                  array_keys($glossary));                                    // Step 1
$res = preg_replace_callback($pttrns, function ($m) use($glossary){          // Step 2
    return str_replace(strtolower($m[0]), $m[0],              
                                     $glossary[strtolower($m[0])]);         // Step 3
}, $text);
```